# Not able to get modules through require in bliss template node.js

Tags: node.js

I am using bliss for parsing templates.  I am trying to load few modules inside bliss template. but getting error : " require is not defined"

sample code:

@@!(objmodel)

@{

var fs = require('fs'); // getting error at this line

.........
}

The application through which bliss is called already has fs module.  which it is using.

Comment: It is very suspicious to import modules in a template file. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to add some logic in template such as xml parsing or document or creating or reading a temp file created during execution of template. I am not using Bliss for HTML parsing.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read in the [documentation](https://github.com/cstivers78/bliss/wiki#scope_context), it appears that the template engine has its own global and template-scoped contexts. And `require` is most not present in it by default.

My advice would be passing that code snippet to a server-side function:

```
function doSomeFileIO(filename) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    // ...
    return result; // if a result is desired
}
```

And provide the function to either the global context (as in the example below) or the template-context.

```
bliss = new Bliss({
  context: {
    doSomeFileIO: doSomeFileIO
  }
});
```